# QGIS doesn't read raster layer CRS properly - ESRI:54004 instead of EPSG:3857

Tags: raster, coordinate-system

I've switched versions from 3.4 to 3.12 and now QGIS reads rasters created in older QGIS wrong. When I'm clicking "Set CRS - Set Project CRS from Layer" to check it out it shows ESRI:54004 (don't know what this is). When I set raster CRS manually to EPSG:3857 it's all fine. My question is why QGIS dosen't read EPSG:3857 from raster? Is it my fault, or is it bug? Should I re-save all my rasters?